# WPF Static Status Bar Message Access

Tags: wpf

I am creating a WPF application and in the MainWindow.xaml code I have a status bar. I have a StatusBarMessage property which is bound to the status bar. I want this property to be static so that I can update the message in any of the view models. Does anyone have suggestion about the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to bind to and raise change notifications for a static property:

```
public class StatusBarViewModel
{
    private static string _status;
    public static string Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Status)));
        }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:StatusBarViewModel.Status)}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I initialize StaticPropertyChanged?

Comment: @user2582770: You don't. The framework subscribes to the event automatically when you bind to the property. You can run my sample code as-is.

Comment: I know you said that the framework should subscribe to the event, but when debugging, the StaticPropertyChanged property is null so nothing is invoked. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I think so. So I'm using that xaml snippet you provided. In the XML namespace, i've pointed local as follows xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModel"

Comment: How do I bind the property?

Comment: @user2582770: Look at my example.

Comment: The issue was in the XAML code I had. In the Binding I had UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged. I thought if I changed it to UpdateSourceTrigger=StaticPropertyChanged it would work, but it did not. Any idea why?